# sql query select two periods for revenue

Tags: sql, postgresql

how is it possible to compare two period using one query for example:

```
SELECT s_campaign_id, COALESCE(SUM(f_revenue),0) AS revenue FROM tbl_reports WHERE (d_gen_date>='2020-12-15' AND d_gen_date<='2020-12-16') GROUP BY s_campaign_id
```

and have compare this with revenue of other period in the same query so for example i will want to get a list of revenue of period 1 +   period 2

```
SELECT s_campaign_id, COALESCE(SUM(f_revenue),0) AS revenue FROM tbl_reports WHERE (d_gen_date>='2020-12-15' AND d_gen_date<='2020-12-16') as revenue1  AND (d_gen_date>='2019-12-13' AND d_gen_date<='2020-12-14') as revenue2 GROUP BY s_campaign_id
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use FILTER:

```
SELECT
    s_campaign_id
    , COALESCE ( SUM ( f_revenue ) FILTER(WHERE d_gen_date >= '2020-12-15' AND d_gen_date <= '2020-12-16'), 0 ) AS revenue1 
    , COALESCE ( SUM ( f_revenue ) FILTER(WHERE d_gen_date >= '2019-12-13' AND d_gen_date <= '2020-12-14'), 0 ) AS revenue2 
FROM
    tbl_reports 
WHERE
    ( d_gen_date >= '2020-12-15' AND d_gen_date <= '2020-12-16' )
OR  
    ( d_gen_date >= '2019-12-13' AND d_gen_date <= '2020-12-14' ) 
GROUP BY
    s_campaign_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation and `OR` as follows:

```
SELECT s_campaign_id, 
       SUM(case when d_gen_date>='2020-12-15' AND d_gen_date<='2020-12-16' 
                then f_revenue end) AS revenue1,
       SUM(case when d_gen_date>='2020-12-13' AND d_gen_date<='2020-12-14' \ 
                then f_revenue end) AS revenue2
  FROM tbl_reports 
 WHERE (d_gen_date>='2020-12-15' AND d_gen_date<='2020-12-16')  
    OR (d_gen_date>='2019-12-13' AND d_gen_date<='2020-12-14')
GROUP BY s_campaign_id
```

Comment: thanks, if revenue is null how can it be set to 0?